# Dynamically created table is not showing again after removing

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I am facing a problem that is so small but cant make it.I have a master table from where I took some header and column data and bind those data in another dynamic created table .Its working fine .But the problem is when I remove the dynamic generated table and try again to re-create it as I did before it is not working.

My jquery code is like below

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
  $("#table1").find("thead").each(function(){
    $table1Head=$(this).find("th");
    $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(1).text()+ " </th>");
    $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(3).text()+ " </th>");
  });

  $("#table1 tbody").find("tr").each(function(){
    $table2data=$(this).find("td");
    $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr> <td><input type='text'     
 name='first_name[]' value="+$table2data.eq(1).text()+"></td> <td><input  
 type='text' name='last_name[]' value="+$table2data.eq(3).text()+"> 
 </td></tr>");

  });
});
$(document).on("click","#clear",function(){
  $("#table2").empty();
});
```

A working fiddle with full code is added below

[Live Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/8shhnmpm/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click","#clear",function(){

$("#table2 thead").empty();
$("#table2 tbody").empty();

});
```

In your submit function your adding the rows in  `thead` and `tbody`. And in clear function you are clearing the complete table including `thead` and `tbody`.

So you have to prevent these tag also and need to clear the html inside of `thead` and `tbody` only.

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8shhnmpm/6/)

Comment: Thank you .easy solution .I knew it .

Answer (score 1):

When you clear `table2` you remove the `<thead>` and the `<tbody>` element. Somehow the submit button isn't working anymore.

You can try this:

```
$('#clear').click(function(){

$("#table2 thead").empty();
$("#table2 tbody").empty();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/8shhnmpm/8/

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    $("#table2").find('thead').empty().siblings('tbody').empty();
    $("#table1").find("thead").each(function(){
    $table1Head=$(this).find("th");
    $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(1).text()+ " </th>");
    $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(3).text()+ " </th>");
  });
  $("#table1 tbody").find("tr").each(function(){
    $table2data=$(this).find("td");
    $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr> <td><input type='text' name='first_name[]' value="+$table2data.eq(1).text()+"></td> <td><input type='text' name='last_name[]' value="+$table2data.eq(3).text()+"></td></tr>");
  });
});

$(document).on("click","#clear",function(){
  $("#table2").find('thead').empty().siblings('tbody').empty();
});


//Neww For Change 


$(document).on('keydown', 'input[name="last_name[]"]', function(e){
-1!==$.inArray(e.keyCode,[46,8,9,27,13,110,190])||/65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode)&&(!0===e.ctrlKey||!0===e.metaKey)||35<=e.keyCode&&40>=e.keyCode||(e.shiftKey||48>e.keyCode||57<e.keyCode)&&(96>e.keyCode||105<e.keyCode)&&e.preventDefault()
});

//Event Fire for product
$(document).on('focusin','input[name="last_name[]"]', function(){
    //console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
}).on('change', 'input[name="last_name[]"]',function(){

 var prev = $(this).data('val');
 var current = $(this).val();
 var diff=parseInt(prev)-parseInt(current);
 if(current==0)
 {
 alert("Quantity Can Not Be 0");
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="last_name[]"]').val(prev);
 }
 else if(diff<0)
{

alert("Quantity Can Not Be Negative");
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="last_name[]"]').val(prev);
} 
else

{
 var name=$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="first_name[]"]').val();
//console.log("name value " + name);
//console.log("recent value " + current);
//console.log("recent value " + diff);
var data="<tr><td><input type='text' name='first_name[]'/></td> <td><input type='text'  name='last_name[]'/></td></tr>";
    $(data).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr')) 
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input[name="last_name[]"]').val(diff);
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input[name="first_name[]"]').val(name);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>   
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Goku</td>
      <td>ABDF</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>100</td>      
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Goku</td>
      <td>WWWDR</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>100</td>   
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Goku</td>
      <td>ADFGRA</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>100</td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="submit" id='clear' value="Clear" />
<br/>

<br/>

<table id="table2" border="1" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
  
</thead>
<tbody>
  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Only added code
`$("#table2").find('thead').empty().siblings('tbody').empty();`
to submit button & clear button.

If you don't add the code to submit button then it will continue to added `tr` & `td` to `table2`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: A different solution ,Thanks it also helps!!